# Render a view's output later via a delayed_job

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If I render html I get html to the browser which works great.  However, how can I get a route's response (the html) when being called in a module or class.

I need to do this because I'm sending documents to DocRaptor and rather than store the markup/html in a db column I would like to instead store record IDs and create the markup when the job executes.

A possible solution is using Ruby's HTTP library, Httparty or wget or something and open up the route and use the response.body.  Before doing so I thought I'd ask around.

Thanks!

-- Update --

Here's something like what I ended up going with:

Quick tip - in case anyone does this and need their helper methods you need to extend AV with ApplicationHelper:

Here's something like what I ended up doing:

```
av = ActionView::Base.new()
av.view_paths = ActionController::Base.view_paths
av.extend ApplicationHelper #or any other helpers your template may need
body = av.render(:template => "orders/receipt.html.erb",:locals => {:order => order})
```

Link:
http://www.rigelgroupllc.com/blog/2011/09/22/render-rails3-views-outside-of-your-controllers/

Comment: Quick note - put simply how can I do 'render_to_string' from a module or class later.  So rather than render_to_string in a controller - how can I achieve that same output later via DJ.

Comment: Any starter code you can supply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this question out, it contains the code probably want in an answer:

[Rails 3 > Rendering views in rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752454/rails-3-rendering-views-in-rake-task)

Comment: I think this will do it - thanks!  I just needed a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Quick tip - in case anyone does this and need their helper methods you need to extend ActionView ApplicationHelper